# Can Qt's `moc` and/or `uic` be made to treat warnings as errors?

Tags: qt, moc, uic

As we've worked to move more and more of our codebase to a warnings-as-errors model, one thing I've noticed is that warnings spit out by `uic` and `moc` still slip through uncaught. Things like:

```
foo.ui: Warning: The name 'widget' (QWidget) is already in use, defaulting to 'widget1'
bar.ui: Warning: Invalid signal/slot connection: "button" -> "OnClicked".
baz.h:0: Note: No relevant classes found. No output generated.
```

Is there any means of making these tools treat these warnings as fatal errors?

Comment: No, apart from this the first and third warning are really just information without any drawback.

Comment: The first means there's an ambiguity in the object names. The third means the build system is wasting time running `moc` on a file that doesn't need it. Obviously neither is a huge problem, but they are worth cleaning up.